# Setting a value from true to false react native hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a value that is true, but I need to set it false when an input is empty on submit, for some reason I'm not able to set the values from true to false.

This is my code:

```
const [cellError, setcellError] = useState(true);
const [passError, setpassError] = useState(true);

CheckTextInput = () => {
    if (vCellphone != '') {
        onSubmit({ vCellphone, vPassword, loading })
      } else {
        setcellError(false);
      }
    }
  };
 return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
    <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
      placeholder="Teléfono"
      underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
      onChangeText={newvCellphone => setvCellphone(newvCellphone)}
      keyboardType={'numeric'}
      value={vCellphone}
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoCompleteType = "off"
      maxLength = {10}
    />
  </View>
  {cellError != true ?
      <Text style={{ color: "red" }}> Se requiere numero de telefono</Text>  : null}

  <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]}  
    onPress={() => CheckTextInput()}
  >
    <Text style={styles.loginText}>INGRESAR</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
  );
};
```

For some reason the `setcellError(false);` and `setpassError(false)` aren't working, any advice?

Comment: What makes you say its not working?

Comment: This logic `{cellError != true ?` looks backwards. Wouldn't you want to show the error message when `cellError == true`?

Comment: it Works, but doesnt Works its weird, when i load my page bot inputs triggers the validation (i dont want this, i want the button to trigger the status of the validation), 
another thing is that when i press the button the second input deletes the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onPress={() => CheckTextInput()}` to `onPress={this.CheckTextInput}`.

Change `cellError != true` to `cellError == true`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useEffect` to update your component.

You can try:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (vCellphone === '') setcellError(false)
}, [vCellphone])
```